# F# SQL Serve Handshake Errors after upgrading from .net 6 to .net 7

Tags: f#, sql-server-express, .net-7.0, f#-data

I am trying to upgrade from .net 6 to.net 7 in my solution and I have intermittent issues when trying to connect to SQL server Express.

> Message=Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while
> attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
> could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
> unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
> to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=21045;
> handshake=9;    Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
> StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

my connection strings look like this:

```
module Connections2 =
    open FSharp.Data.Sql

    let [<Literal>] artooConnString = "Server=tcp:r2hserver;Database=Artoo;User 
Id=sa;Password=xxxxxxx;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"
    let [<Literal>] smBoomConnString = "Server=tcp:r2hserver;Database=SMboom;User 
Id=sa;Password=xxxxxxx;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"
    type artooProvider =
        SqlDataProvider<
            Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
            artooConnString,
            IndividualsAmount = 1000,
            UseOptionTypes = Common.NullableColumnType.VALUE_OPTION>

    type smBoomProvider =
        SqlDataProvider<
            Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
            smBoomConnString,
            IndividualsAmount = 1000,
            UseOptionTypes = Common.NullableColumnType.VALUE_OPTION>
```

Sometimes if I reboot it will work for a while but I have rolled everything back to .net 6 and it all works fine.  Ideas?